# Efficient select and distinct on a large association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have three models: `Catalog`, `Product` and `Value`.
The `Value` table has a `characteristic_id` column, and I'd like to get the list of different `characteristic_id` on a set of `values`.

The relationships are:

- a `catalog` has many `products`
- a `product` has many `values`

Here is the query I came up with:

```
Value.joins(:product).select(:characteristic_id).distinct.where(products: {catalog_id: catalog.id}).pluck(:characteristic_id)
=> [441, 2582, 3133]
```

which returns the right result, but it is extremely slow on a large catalog with a million products (about 50 seconds).
I can't find a more efficient way to do this.

Here is an `EXPLAIN` of the query:

```
=> EXPLAIN for: SELECT DISTINCT "values"."characteristic_id" FROM "values" INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."id" = "values"."product_id" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = $1 [["catalog_id", 1767]]
                                                      QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=1515106.82..1515109.15 rows=233 width=4)
   Group Key: "values".characteristic_id
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=124703.76..1492245.65 rows=9144469 width=4)
         Hash Cond: ("values".product_id = products.id)
         ->  Seq Scan on "values"  (cost=0.00..1002863.07 rows=34695107 width=8)
         ->  Hash  (cost=114002.20..114002.20 rows=652285 width=4)
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on products  (cost=12311.64..114002.20 rows=652285 width=4)
                     Recheck Cond: (catalog_id = 1767)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_products_on_catalog_id  (cost=0.00..12148.57 rows=652285 width=0)
                           Index Cond: (catalog_id = 1767)
(10 rows)
```

Any idea on how to run this query faster?

Comment: Have you tried to `EXPLAIN` this query?

Comment: @Зелёный see the edit, I've added the EXPLAIN

Comment: How about `EXPLAIN ANALIZE`?

Comment: One major problem that I see here is that there is no limit to this query - so if the values table holds millions of records the result set will be huge and exhaust the available memory.

Comment: One tip that I recommend is asking this as a seperate "pure SQL" question and tagging it with the database (`postgresql` or `mysql`) as those tags have more followers by an order of magnitude and tend to get better answers than Rails questions. Just create an example of the tables, data and expected result.

Comment: Is this for reporting? I ask, because if it is, you might want to consider denormalizing this data into another table/db just for reporting purposes. For example, you could then stick category ID on each of your values. That way you can get rid of the JOIN all together an just query a single table. This way you're taking the work you'd be doing during query time, and moving it to the time it takes to load and manipulate the data to get into the reporting system.

Comment: @GrahamSlick have you considered db partitioning?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have indexes on both foreign keys:

- index `"values"."product_id"`
- index `"products"."catalog_id"`

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to add an index on `values.characteristic_id`.
2. Oftentimes `GROUP BY` may be faster than `DISTINCT` :

   Value.joins(:product).where(products: {catalog_id: catalog.id}).select(:characteristic_id).group(:characteristic_id).pluck(:characteristic_id)